# Help in understanding a math question

Tags: geometry

The Question Is:

BH is an altitude of triangle ABC. Let K and P be points symmetric to H with
respect to AB and BC respectively. Prove that KP intersects AB and BC at the bases of the other two altitudes of triangle ABC.

The second line of the problem really throws me off. Any help in understanding this question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Say that perpendicular from H to AB intersects AB at point X.  Then K is the point on that perpendicular such that |HX| = |KX|.  That is, K is the mirror image of H reflected in the line AB.  P is defined similarly.  Does this make it clear?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This is how the points are situated:

[image]

And this is the claim you have to show:

[image]

Comment: I think you switched the positions of K and P.

Comment: do you know how to prove this statement?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Refer to the diagram for the proof of the statement:

Since CYXA is cyclic due to the altitude lines HX and AY, $ \angle BCA = 180 -\angle YXA $. BXHC is cyclic due to the altitude lines BH and CX and

$$ \angle HXA = 180 - \angle BXH = \angle BCA = 180 -\angle YXA $$

Also, because P is the mirror image of H respect to XA,

$$\angle PXA = \angle HXA = 180 - \angle YXA$$

Thus, the points P, X and Y are colinear.

Similarly, the points K, Y and X are colinear. Therefore, KP intersects AB and BC at the bases of the other two altitudes of ABC.